# "git merge --squash" with libgit2

Tags: git, libgit2

Is it possible to perform a squash-type merge through libgit2?

Adding some filler words to satisfy SO's "inadequate" message size restriction. I know, it's beyond ridiculous :D

Answer (score 2):

The typical merge workflow involves calling `git_merge` to merge into the working directory and index, checking for conflicts, and then calling `git_commit` with multiple parents (the HEAD and the upstream commits you're merging).

To emulate --squash simply omit the commit (or commit with HEAD as the only parent). In either case you want to explicitly clean up the merge state with `git_repository_state_cleanup`.